# How to retrieve image from an Oracle database and display in JSP in Struts

Tags: java, image, jsp, struts

Good day,

I have upload an image file and store it in oracle database.  In Oracle SQL Developer, the image data display as "(BLOB)" .

Now I would like to retrive some data from my database and display in jsp. The following is part of my code of actiaon.java file :

```
thisForm.setCampaignName(cbo.getCampaignName());
thisForm.setImageDisplay(cbo.getImage());
```

The following is part of my code in form.java file (which the getter setter method):

```
private String campaignName = null;

private byte[] imageDisplay = null;

public String getCampaignName() {
    return campaignName;
}

public void setCampaignName(String campaignName) {
    this.campaignName = campaignName;
} 

public byte[] getImageDisplay() {
    return imageDisplay;
}

public void setImageDisplay(byte[] imageDisplay) {
    this.imageDisplay = imageDisplay;
}
```

And the following is part of code in my jsp file:

```
<td class="value"><html:text property="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>

<td class="value"><bean:write name="campaignListingForm" property="imageDisplay" /></td>
```

The `campaignName` was display correct in browser as what I key in and store in oracle database. However, the image does not display correctly.
It just display `[B@5df25df2` word in my browser.

I think i am wrong in displaying the image using JSP.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Show how do you retrieve the data because the data might not be available, and any solutions out there might not be working.

Comment: Hi Roman, the first part of code in my post is the way to retrieve the data from database. The `campaignName` was display correctly, so I think the data should be available. Do you means I need to show how is the code of `cbo.getCampaignName()` working?

Answer (score 0):

The image is a binary data. You can't display it directly in your page. You have to have an IMG tag in your page with its **src** attribute set to another method in your struts action which retrieves the image id (appended at the end of the image url in src property), fetches the given image and sends it to the client using an appropriate mime/type. So the sequence would be as follow:

1. You fetch your data (company information) from data base
2. Implement a method which given a company name (id is preferred if you have), that loads the company image from DB and writes it down to the response output stream with an appropriate mime-type (something like the one mentioned by @Guillaume)
3. Generate an appropriate **img** element on your result page (the page which displays company information) and set is src property to the url of the action developed in step 2. Make sure you pass company name (or id) as a query string parameter